# Reflection custom type returns null

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, null

The following code (found on StackOverflow) works:

```
object ob = new { Name = "Erwin Okken", Age = 23, Position = new Point(2, 5) };
Type type = ob.GetType();
PropertyInfo pr = type.GetProperty("Name");
string value = pr.GetValue(ob, null).ToString(); // Erwin Okken
```

However, if I use my own class, it does not work:

```
public class Subject
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
    public Point Position;

    public string Stringtest;
    public int IntTest;

    public Subject()
    {

    }
}

Type type = ob.GetType();
PropertyInfo pr = type.GetProperty("Name"); // null
string value = pr.GetValue(ob, null).ToString();
```

I tried all Bindingflags, but the variable "pr" stays null. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: `Name` is a field not property, change it to property `public string Name { get; set; }` or use `type.GetField`.

Comment: what is mean for 'ob' is it object from Subject?

Comment: @Alessandro this is the correct answer (most likely), so should be given as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this:

```
public class Subject
{
    public string Name;
    ...
}
```

In your type definition `Name` is a field not a property, you have to change your type to this:

```
public class Subject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Altenatively if you want to mantain `Name` as field (bad idea) you can use:

```
FieldInfo pr = type.GetField("Name");
```